# python continuous integration

Tags: python, continuous-integration

I am looking to set up a continuous integration server for a python project. Normally this would build the project however as python is not built as such, what should be done instead? Just unit tests? Or are there additional steps that anyone can recommend?

Comment: Why have folks voted to close this?

Comment: @yegor256 the question is not about where to build, but more what should go into a python build. We settled on static analysis and unit tests running on an internal server with jenkins. As we already had some jenkins deployments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of excellent recourses on how to use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) together with Python:

- [Talk from PyCon](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/hudson-pycon)
- [A blog post](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/python-love-story-virtualenv-and-hudson).
- [Another blog post](http://www.rhonabwy.com/wp/2009/11/04/setting-up-a-python-ci-server-with-hudson/).

The standard option would be to run the unittests, record the test coverage and run pylint or some other style checker.

Comment: Thanks, these resources are exactly the sort of thing I was after

Answer (score 0):

Using Jenkins/Hudson for continuous integration is the standard approach.